# How to exec into an init container?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

```
$ kubectl version

Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"9", GitVersion:"v1.9.6", GitCommit:"9f8ebd171479bec0ada837d7ee641dec2f8c6dd1", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-03-21T15:21:50Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"9", GitVersion:"v1.9.6", GitCommit:"9f8ebd171479bec0ada837d7ee641dec2f8c6dd1", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-03-21T15:13:31Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Looking at the [Sonarqube helm chart](https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/tree/master/stable/sonarqube)

**requirements.yaml**

```
dependencies:
- name: sonarqube
  version: 0.5.0
  repository: https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/
```

Trying to install the latest version of the java plugin:

**values.yaml**

```
plugins:
   install:
     - "http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/sonarsource/java/sonar-java-plugin/5.3.0.13828/sonar-java-plugin-5.3.0.13828.jar"
```

However, I am getting an error on the init container:

```
$ kubectl logs sonarqube-sonarqube-7b5dfd84cf-sglk5 -c install-plugins

sh: /opt/sonarqube/extensions/plugins/install_plugins.sh: Permission denied
```

---

```
$ kubectl describe po sonarqube-sonarqube-7b5dfd84cf-sglk5

Name:           sonarqube-sonarqube-7b5dfd84cf-sglk5
Namespace:      default
Node:           docker-for-desktop/192.168.65.3
Start Time:     Thu, 19 Apr 2018 15:22:04 -0500
Labels:         app=sonarqube
                pod-template-hash=3618984079
                release=sonarqube
Annotations:    <none>
Status:         Pending
IP:             10.1.0.250
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/sonarqube-sonarqube-7b5dfd84cf
Init Containers:
  install-plugins:
    Container ID:  docker://b090f52b95d36e03b8af86de5a6729cec8590807fe23e27689b01e5506604463
    Image:         joosthofman/wget:1.0
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://joosthofman/wget@sha256:74ef45d9683b66b158a0acaf0b0d22f3c2a6e006c3ca25edbc6cf69b6ace8294
    Port:          <none>
    Command:
      sh
      -c
      /opt/sonarqube/extensions/plugins/install_plugins.sh
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
```

**Is there a way to `exec` into the into the init container?**

My attempt:

```
$ kubectl exec -it sonarqube-sonarqube-7b5dfd84cf-sglk5 -c install-plugins sh

error: unable to upgrade connection: container not found ("install-plugins")
```

---

**Update**

With @WarrenStrange's suggestion:

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                                    READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
sonarqube-postgresql-59975458c6-mtfjj   1/1       Running   0          11m
sonarqube-sonarqube-685bd67b8c-nmj2t    1/1       Running   0          11m

$ kubectl get pods sonarqube-sonarqube-685bd67b8c-nmj2t -o yaml
...
 initContainers:
  - command:
    - sh
    - -c
    - 'mkdir -p /opt/sonarqube/extensions/plugins/ && cp /tmp/scripts/install_plugins.sh
      /opt/sonarqube/extensions/plugins/install_plugins.sh && chmod 0775 /opt/sonarqube/extensions/plugins/install_plugins.sh
      && /opt/sonarqube/extensions/plugins/install_plugins.sh '
    image: joosthofman/wget:1.0
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: install-plugins
    resources: {}
    terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
    terminationMessagePolicy: File
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /opt/sonarqube/extensions
      name: sonarqube
      subPath: extensions
    - mountPath: /tmp/scripts/
      name: install-plugins
    - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
      name: default-token-89d9n
      readOnly: true
...
```

Create a new pod manifest extracted from the init container manifest. Replace the command with `sleep 6000` and execute the commands. This allows you to poke around.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The issue is that the container does not exist (see the CrashLoopBackOff).

One of the things that I do with init containers (assuming you have the source) is to put a sleep 600 on failure in the entrypoint. At least for debugging.  This lets you exec into the container to poke around to see the cause of the failure.

Answer (score 1):

Given this:

```
$ kubectl logs sonarqube-sonarqube-7b5dfd84cf-sglk5 -c install-plugins

sh: /opt/sonarqube/extensions/plugins/install_plugins.sh: Permission denied
```

It seems that `Permission denied` is the actual error that happened inside the `install-plugin` container. You can diagnose the `joosthofman/wget:1.0` by spinning it up locally `docker run -it --rm joosthofman/wget:1.0 sh`. This will give you a shell into the container so you can check out its runtime contents.

I did it myself and, for one thing, the script it's trying to execute does not even exist inside the container.

```
/ # ls -l /opt/sonarqube/extensions/plugins/install_plugins.sh
ls: /opt/sonarqube/extensions/plugins/install_plugins.sh: No such file or directory
```

Comment: If you don't have tons of environment variables then simply pull the image (used to create the init container) and run the command will tell you the root cause. 
However "kubectl logs <pod_name> -c <container_name>" is much easier if you have those variables.